# Why does my program not end after I input the measurements for the area of a certain shape?

Tags: c++, function

My program is having issues. It runs through the function but it just keeps repeating. It's not really an infinite loop but it goes back to where it asks for the measurement.

I'm pretty much stumped at having the program end.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

char getShapeType();    
double getAreaOfRectangle(double, double);    
double getAreaOfCircle(double, double);    
double getAreaOfTriangle(double, double);    
double getAreaOfSquare(double);    

char getShapeType()    
{char type;

cout << "This program will compute area of a shape.\n"
    << "What is the shape type?\n"
    << "Circle or Rectangle or Square or Triangle? (C or R or S or T): ";
cin >> type;

// Validate the shape type.
while (type != 'C' && type != 'c' &&
    type != 'R' && type != 'r' && type != 'S' && type != 's'
    && type != 'T' && type != 't')
{
    cout << "Please enter C or R or S or T: ";
    cin >> type;
}

// Convert lowercase to uppercase.
if (type == 'c')
    type = 'C';

else if (type == 'r')
        type = 'R';

else if (type == 's')
        type = 'S';

else if (type == 't')
        type = 'T';

return type;}

int main()   
{    
char shapeType;                                 //R=rectangle, T=triangle, C=circle, S= square    
double areaOfRectangle;                         //variable to store the area of rectangle    
double areaOfCircle;                            //variable to store the area of circle    
double areaOfTriangle;                          //variable to store the area of triangle    
double areaOfSquare;                            //variable to store the area of circle    

// Get the shape type.
shapeType = getShapeType();

//Rectangle
while (shapeType == 'R')
{
    double width;
    double length;

    do
    {
        cout << "Enter width and length of rectangle separated by space: " << endl;
        cin >> width >> length;
    } while (width <= 0 || length <= 0);

    areaOfRectangle = getAreaOfRectangle(width, length);
    cout << "The area of rectangle with width "
        << width << " and length " << length
        << " is " << areaOfRectangle << endl;

}

//Circle
while (shapeType == 'C')
{
    const double PI = 3.14159265359;
    double radius;

    do
    {
        cout << "Enter the radius of circle: " << endl;
        cin >> radius;
    } while (radius <= 0);

    areaOfCircle = getAreaOfCircle(PI, radius);
    cout << "The area of circle with PI "
        << PI << " and radius " << radius
        << " is " << areaOfCircle << endl;
}

//Triangle
while (shapeType == 'T')
{
    double base;
    double height;

    do
    {
        cout << "Enter base and height of triangle separated by space: " << endl;
        cin >> base >> height;
    } while (base <= 0 || height <= 0);

    areaOfTriangle = getAreaOfTriangle(base, height);
    cout << "The area of triangle with base "
        << base << " and height " << height
        << " is " << areaOfTriangle << endl;
}

//Square
while (shapeType == 'S')
{
    double width;

    do
    {
        cout << "Enter width of square separated by space: " << endl;
        cin >> width;
    } while (width <= 0);

    areaOfSquare = getAreaOfSquare(width);
    cout << "The area of square with width "
        << width
        << " is " << areaOfSquare << endl;}

}


double getAreaOfRectangle(double width, double length)
{    
double area = width * length;

return area;}


double getAreaOfCircle(double PI, double radius)
{    
double area = PI * radius * radius;

return area;}


double getAreaOfTriangle(double base, double height)
{    
double area = (base * height) / 2;

return area;}


double getAreaOfSquare(double width)
{    
double area = width * 2;

return area;}
```

I have changed all the "while" in my int main to "if" but now a new problem rose up. The debug window just closes after I input the measurements.

Edit: Thank you for the help! I changed "while" to "if" and it didn't output. I just realized my system pause was after my return 0; and that was the issue. Now it works perfectly fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `main()` function, you have:

```
while (shapeType == 'R')
{
    /* do stuff */
}
```

But you never change `shapeType` inside the loop, so it keeps repeating.

You don't need a loop there....you need a series of `if` statements to pick the right shape and process it.

Comment: I'm starting to make sense of it. When I change it to if, it'll stop it from being a loop and now it'll turn into pretty much a true or false statement.

Now the debug just closes when I input the measurements?

Comment: Dear @Thomas,  What he meant was.. change all 4 `while (shapeType == 'R')` that you have in the main() function to  `if(shapeType == 'R')`  form..

Comment: @p._phidot_ Yes, I've changed all the "while" to "if" but now a new complete issue rose up that has stumped me even more. Now it doesn't output anything and just closes after I input the measurements. 

I apologize if I don't make any sense, it's my first programming class.

Comment: mind sharing the updated codes? || on of the key to troubleshooting a code is.. to identify which part work and which part doesn't. || In you case.. you may start by commenting line 55 to line 123, and add `cout << shapeType << endl;` at  line 53 to check whether the `shapeType` varable get the value you intended.. || then do the same for every next section sections : uncomment, run, check. And repeat : uncomment, run, check. || A big program is always built on small programs.. This will make sure every small part works.. then you can worry about the big program sequence.